# How call java vararg method from C with valist

Tags: java, java-native-interface, variadic-functions

I have C method with varargs

```
void message(int id,  ...)
```

And it should call Java static method with vararg

```
public static void message(String messageName, String ... args)
```

How can I do it using C valist and JNI API?

Thank you!

Comment: Not an expert with either Java or JNI, but Java varargs are essentially Arrays, while C varargs are... messy and unsafe. Your C function probably needs to build up the array properly and invoke the Java function with that.

Comment: Yes, I can build an object array, but  I expect that exists more nice solution. For example java constructor invocation has method that receive C valist

Comment: @Pavel: I think you're overestimating JNI.  Are you open to using JNA?  I know that it can create Java varargs methods that wrap C varargs functions, I don't know if it would be able to do the opposite.

Answer (score 9):

Your not likely to get any use out of passing the address of a va_list up to Java.  Here are a few snippets showing how to pass up an array using "..." and va_list.  Add error/exception/return checking as necessary.

In Java:

```
static private void javaDefineArray(Object ... args) { 
    for (Object o : args) {
        print("javaDefineArray " + o);
    }
}
```

In C:

```
// Lookup the method using GetMethodID or GetStaticMethodID
mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, class, "javaDefineArray", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)V");

// C function taking variable args ( all String in this example )
static void javaDefineArray(JNIEnv * env, jobject o, ...) {
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  char * msg[100+1] = {0};  // 100 args max
  jobjectArray ja;
  va_list list;
  va_start(list, o);
  do {msg[count] = va_arg(list,char *);
  } while(msg[count] !=0 && ++count < 100); // end/saftey check
  va_end(list);
  ja = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ""));
  for(i=0;i!=count;i++) {
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,ja,i,(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, msg[i]));
  }
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, o, mid, ja);
}
```

C Usage:

```
javaDefineArray(env, o, "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", NULL);
```

Java Output:

```
javaDefineArray 0
javaDefineArray 1
javaDefineArray 2
javaDefineArray 3
javaDefineArray 4
```

Comment: what if you don't know vararg args type? let's say invocation was `javaDefineArray(env, o, "0", 1, "56", 17.3) ` ?

Comment: Create a new question and reference this question and let's see if someone can assist with the problem.